# automatic plesk configuration change

Tags: configuration

i have server A with domain aaa.com

i also installed server B with same domain aaa.com

they are at the same company, and they have the same domain name, but they are separate servers, A on production, B not on production yet

a weird thing is that after using B few hours the configuration of server B gets updated with information from server A

server B gets server A ip address (with red error icon), all the A domains list, tries to load same certificate when i try to restart it and plesk even gets language interface change from server A

i didn't touch any plesk configuration, the only thing i did was adding to server B aaa.com domain in plesk, copied very simple vhost.conf file and run

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/websrvmng -a
```

on server B

i tried reinstalling the new server but after few hours of normal usage, all the plesk config gets overwritten again.

how is it possible? where from does automatic plesk configuration come from? (like the file /etc/httpd/conf.d/zz010_psa_httpd.conf)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out the reason of this happening

plesk stores all the information in mysql database and while i was importing information from server A i moved also all databases sql dump to server B and inserted it there, overwriting all plesk configuration.

So, the answer is, plesk configuration (which gets overwritten every sometime) comes from mysql db.